# Prove that $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$ is not Lipschitz continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Show that none of the functions $f(x)=\sqrt[n]{x}$, for $n\in \Bbb N$, $n\ge2$ are Lipschitz continuous.

So i did it this way:
$|\sqrt[n]{x}-\sqrt[n]{y}|=|x-y||\frac{1}{x^{\frac{n-1}{n}}+x^{\frac{n-2}{n}}y^{\frac{1}{n}}+...+x^{\frac{1}{n}}y^{\frac{n-2}{n}}+y^{\frac{n-1}{n}}}| \le (?)L|x-y|$
and argued that for very small x and y (close to 0) the denominator is very small, therefore the whole expressions is big, and the whole fraction cannot be limited by a real number (L),  so these functions are not Lipschitz continuous.

Am I corrected? Is there any nicer, more formal way to show it?

Comment: In your question you say that the function evaluates on $\mathbb N$, but then in your proof you want "$x$ and $y$ close to $0$". Which one is it? Anyway, I have addressed this in my answer.

Comment: There's no information about x, so i assumed $x \in \Bbb R$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks fine to me. A similar way is to note that being Lipschitz would mean there's an $L$ such that
$$\bigg|{\sqrt[n]{y} - \sqrt[n]{x} \over y - x} \bigg| \leq L$$
Letting $y = 2x$ means that for all $x$ one must have
$$(\sqrt[n]{2} - 1)x^{{1 \over n} - 1} \leq L$$
Letting $x \rightarrow 0$ gives a contradiction

If you're including $x = 0$ in your domain (you didn't say) then you could take $x = 0$ in the above and let $y \rightarrow 0$ to get a similar contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument shows that if $x,y$ are bounded away from zero, then the function is indeed Lipschitz (i.e. it is Lipschitz on any interval $(\delta,\infty)$ with $\delta>0$).

So the problem can only arise at $0$. There, with $y=0$, the Lipschitz condition amounts to 
$$
\sqrt[n]x\leq x,
$$
which doesn't hold for $x\in[0,1)$ and $n>1$.